# How to prevent Eclipse from downloading Maven indexes?

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse

Every once in a while, Eclipse spins a java.exe process that downloads gigabytes of Maven indexes.

These huge index files get into the "temp" directory, all named like nexus-maven-repository-index.gzxxx, and they never seem to stop coming. It keeps doing this every time I open Window/Preferences.

Where do I find a control option for this event?

Eclipse version is: Version: 2020-09 (4.17.0) Build id: 20200910-1200

Answer (score 1):

I am on the same version of Eclipse and similarly I've not had this issue with previous versions of Eclipse, but have been afflicted by this since a recent update to the 2020-09 version.

You ought to be able to disable the indexing for Maven repositories by going to the view below:

*Window / Show View / Other / Maven / Maven Repositories*

Then right-clicking and selecting *Index Details Disabled* on the relevant repositories under *Global Repository*

I installed the latest m2eclipse earlier in the week and it doesn't seem to have had an impact so this seems like the nuclear option, but may buy you some time.

For reference, my current m2e version is:

**Eclipse.org - m2e Maven Integration for Eclipse   1.17.0.20201112-0751    org.eclipse.m2e.feature**

Comment: thanks, this nuclear option may have stopped the downloads.. I don't see the m2e version 1.17 available though..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `Preferences > Maven > [ ] Download repository index updates on startup` is unchecked.

Comment: thank you, everything in the Preferences/Maven/General section is disabled except "Do not automatically update dependencies from remote repositories.."